# How to get USB devices List

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I want to get the list of usb devices from the Windows system.

I don't know Win 32 programming and all.

I am using Qt for development, don't have any idea to solve my problem.

I have searched code for that, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, but on [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/)  site I have found such [documentation](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/doc/functions.html), which may be useful for you:

```
usb_init -- Initialize libusb
usb_find_busses -- Finds all USB busses on system
usb_find_devices -- Find all devices on all USB devices
usb_get_busses -- Return the list of USB busses found
```

But!, [here](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-01/thread00107-0.html) some one already asked this question: *Program in QT to control an USB device ?* And the answer is: no.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

i cant use any 3rd party resources

any other ideas

Comment: @new: ideas to do *what* exactly?  You only asked for a list of devices, improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you "to play" with **devcon.exe** (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272).

The last version of the utility **with the source code** you can find in Windows DDK (see and download from http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx). After installation of DDK look in C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\tools\devcon\i386 and C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\setup\devcon directories.

devcon is a very good example what you can do with Device Installation API (SetupDi-API).

Answer (score -1):

You need to call [`GetRawInputDeviceList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetRawInputDeviceInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
also check the [Intel Example](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/usb/examples/DUSBVC.PDF)

Comment: Whats the reason for Downvoting ?

Comment: err, perhaps because it only gets you mouse/keyboard/HID devices? For the record not my d/w!