# How to get only USB devices not all the devices in the system

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Grretings to all,

I get devices list from the system.

but i am not sure that if i want to get only the usb devices currently in the system means ,

What class i must specify in the below code  ( DWORD Flags )

```
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE,
                           0, // Enumerator
                           0,
                           DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get USB devices LIst](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974003/how-to-get-usb-devices-list)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This deals specifically with the WINAPI oppose to libusb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `EnumerateHostController()`.

**Examples**

- [www.intel.com/intelpress/usb/examples/DUSBVC.PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20091007233417/http://www.intel.com/intelpress/usb/examples/DUSBVC.PDF)
- [github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/usb/usbview/enum.c](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/usb/usbview/enum.c)

Additional info and a detailed discussion **[here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/114294-getting-list-usb-devices-listed-system.html)**.